# Vertical Align of SPAN in H1

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align text within a `span` inside a `h1` to the bottom of the `h1` block.

HTML

```
<h1>
    Left
    <span>Right and Bottom</span>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}    
h1 span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

This end up looking like the below - can anyone advise what I can do?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want both baselines to be on the same horizontal line?

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use `position:absolute` instead of the `float`:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  position:relative;
}

h1 span {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/thc9c/1/

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work correctly. It looks like the span looses any padding/margin it might have had (the span is actually lower down than the h1) - do you know how to avoid this? I'd like the bottom of the texts to align

Comment: @KnownColor that's the tricky with aboslute position. But check the link here I provide you another solution http://jsfiddle.net/6n4H6/.

Comment: That's an awesome solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `line-height` to your `h1` rules

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

h1 span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: This almost works, but the span is not quite at the bottom, which becomes more exaggerated at higher zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute position: http://cdpn.io/KBhuG

Comment: Thank you, this appears to work correctly. It looks like the span looses any padding/margin it might have had (the span is actually lower down than the h1) - do you know how to avoid this? I'd like the bottom of the texts to align.

Comment: You can change bottom property on span. Or add margin-bottom on span.

Comment: downvoted because that link is dead and answers need to include the code and a bonus is a link

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out for you:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4sUq9/1/)

The CSS:

```
h1 {
    display:inline;
    font-size: 2em;
}
h1 span {
    line-height: 3.25em;
    float: right;
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Using a line-height property and doing some mathematics, I have found that the perfect line-height for your span is 3.25. I found this via a [calculator](http://pxtoem.com) and also guided by a few other stack overflow questions. Basically the construct is to change your ems to pxs, multiply your px by the golden ratio (1.618) and then convert that number back to ems.

Like so: 2 em is equal to 32px, and then 32px * 1.618 is equal to 58 (rounded) and then 58px is equal to 3.25 ems.